# Twilio Programmable Chat JavaScript SDK (v3) region option causing error

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm currently trying to set the region option when initiating Twilio's Javascript programmable chat helper library (Twilio-chat).

Previously I was using the default settings and mostly the library worked great (some performance issues, hence the desire to switch region). However upon setting the region option to "ie1", I end up with the following response while the client is trying to initiate -

```
status: {
         description: "Can't find Service Instance by Id",
         errorCode: 2001,
         code: 401,
         status: "AUTHENTICATION FAILED"
        }
```

The source of confusion is the fact that switch from US1 to IE1 is causing the client unable to find the service instance while with the default configuration I have no issues with this matter. I've also checked the service identified within the JWT exists.

Has anyone run into this issue before and been able to resolve it?

Comment: I think that the original service you set up is located in the US1 region, so to switch to IE1 you may need to talk to support about it. I would get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) directly and see if they can help.

Comment: @philnash What other regions do they support at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Check your grant service_sid.  Could be it's a different SID since you have changed regions.